# Postgresql turns update to insert and creates duplicate record

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm not quite sure how to ask this question.

The table stores its main data in a JSONB column. The other columns are an integer primary key, a unique text secondary key, an application generated integer transaction id, and the type of operation last performed (insert, update, delete).

There are 5 triggers.

1. On before insert and update, set the new.operation column to TG_OP (more on this later)
2. On before insert, generate a unique 6 digit alphameric code for use in URLs
3. On before insert, generate a unique, random 6 digit numeric code avoiding the German Tank Problem.
4. On before insert, add the numeric and alphameric codes to the JSONB object.
5. On after update and delete, insert the old record appended with the new tranid and operation column to an unindexed archive table.

All of the triggers seem to work and the records get created with the new ids and the ids in the JSONB column.

However, on an update the new operation gets set to update from TG_OP variable, but the record gets inserted into the table creating duplicate keys. Subsequent ops on that record fail because of the duplicate records.

I've stepped through it in the pgAdmin debugger. It seems to go through each trigger correctly. It completes with a record from the insert (e.g. tranid=254, operation=insert) and another from the update (e.g. tranid=256, operation=update). The archive table has one record added which shows the original info was 254/insert and it was replaced by 256/update.

But there are two records in the main table!!!

This is a violation of two uniqueness constraints which should have caused it to fail:

```
CONSTRAINT npprimarykey_id PRIMARY KEY (id),
CONSTRAINT npid_txt_unique UNIQUE (id_txt)
```

Beyond that, the command being executed was an `UPDATE`.

I'd not clear where to look or on what forum to ask the question. Which is the forum the firms building Postgresql frequent?

Thanks,

David

Comment: `... The archive table has ...` So you have *two* tables?

Comment: Note: you can add `RAISE NOTICE 'xyz = %';` to your trigger functions to perform printf-style debugging. This will at least show you the sequence of events.

Comment: It looks like an update that will work correctly until the last instant. It is reporting itself as an update in the triggers. But then it inserts the record rather than do the update. If the update is internally an insert and delete, then it is failing to delete the old record. 

It is violating to integrity constraints on uniqueness. 

Makes zero sense to me.

Comment: Yes...there are two tables, the main table (which ends with  transid and transop columns) and an archive_<table name> table with the same layout but two additional columns, newtranid and new tranop). The record is correctly inserted into the archive table.